# Security Advantages of Azure Sphere vs other embedded OS

Tags: iot, embedded-system

I know Azure Sphere is new, and to my understanding Microsoft is targeting the embedded IOT market, but how is Azure Sphere more secure than other embedded RTOS systems like VxWorks or Integrity? Don't many of the embedded security measures mentioned at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/details/ already exist in most embedded devices? Is it their combination of using hardware and software security measures that will give Azure more security than normal embedded operating systems?

What separates Azure Sphere from other security focused embedded operating systems?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is not more secure. It is just Microsoft being Microsoft. Don't ever trust Microsoft.

Comment: Could you narrow your question down to a specific detail? This seems a bit broad to me, I'm not an IoT expert though.

Comment: With this edit this question is still very broad.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Sphere is not just another IoT operating system, but a unique combination of secure hardware (with a separate security core), secure OS (based on Linux), and a cloud security service. The proprietary hardware for example ensures that an application cannot hack the OS and the application can only access specific authorized servers.